# Accessing slots of an S4 function superclass

Tags: r, r-s4

Can I create an S4 superclass of "function" and access the slots of that object from the function call? At the moment I have:

```
> setClass("pow",representation=representation(pow="numeric"),contains="function")
[1] "pow"
> z=new("pow",function(x){x^2},pow=3)
> z(2)
[1] 4
```

Now what I really want is for the function to be x to the power of the @pow slot of itself, so if I then do:

```
> z@pow=3
```

I get cubes, and if I do:

```
> z@pow=2
```

I get squares.

But I don't see how to get a reference to 'self' like I would do in Python. I'm guessing its somewhere in the environment somewhere...

Here's how it works in python:

```
class Pow:
    def __init__(self,power):
        self.power=power
        self.__call__ = lambda x: pow(x,self.power)

p = Pow(2) # p is now a 'squarer'
print p(2) # prints 4

p.power=3 # p is now a 'cuber'
print p(2) # prints 8
```

Couldn't really be easier, and I didn't even have to do "import antigravity"....

Comment: I think you probably want to use a reference class

Comment: Yeah? Has the S language finally got object-oriented programming right this time?

Comment: If by right, you mean has implemented in a way that you're familiar with from languages like java, then yes.

Comment: I meant in the way that S3 is clearly wrong (but its a very moby hack) and S4 is just unclearly wrong (see above). But yeah, I think in the limit as t->Inf then R->python... Lets get rid of curly braces from R and use indentation....

Comment: With reference classes you'd get 'self' but loose the 'isA' relationship Spacedman asked for (at least in my experiments -- a more complete example?). Also you'd have reference semantics on your pow exponent, which could be quite confusing though consistent with the python implementation.

Comment: But I don't think we want python's mutable semantics. Immutability is much cleaner and easier to reason about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resorting to a little language manipulation

```
setClass("Pow", representation("function", pow="numeric"),
         prototype=prototype(
           function(x) {
               self <- eval(match.call()[[1]])
               x^self@pow
           }, pow=2))
```

and then

```
> f = g = new("Pow")
> g@pow = 3
> f(2)
[1] 4
> g(2)
[1] 8
```

although as Spacedman says things can go wrong

```
> f <- function() { Sys.sleep(2); new("Pow") }
> system.time(f()(2))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.002   0.000   4.005
```

A little more within the lines but deviating from the problem specification and probably no less easy on the eyes is

```
setClass("ParameterizedFunFactory",
         representation(fun="function", param="numeric"),
         prototype=prototype(
           fun=function(x, param) function(x) x^param,
           param=2))

setGeneric("fun", function(x) standardGeneric("fun"))
setMethod(fun, "ParameterizedFunFactory",
          function(x) x@fun(x, x@param))
```

with

```
> f = g = new("ParameterizedFunFactory")
> g@param = 3
> fun(f)(2)
[1] 4
> fun(g)(2)
[1] 8
```

Comment: I might just give you that. Although if you try and do an anonymous object: new("Pow")(3) it actually gets the \@pow slot from another new object created by the eval rather than the one created by the initial "new" call. Not that it makes any difference, and its a very perverse thing to do anyway. eval is nearly always evil.

Comment: Shudder.  You are making my eyes bleed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends what you really want. Is this implementation any closer to your goal?

```
setClass("pow",representation=representation(pow="numeric"),contains="function")
z=new("pow",function(x, pow=3){x^pow})
>  z(2)
[1] 8
 z(2,4)
#[1] 16
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the parent function can be accessed via `sys.function`.

```
setClass("pow", slots = c(pow = "numeric"), contains = "function")
z <- new("pow", function (x) x^(sys.function()@pow), pow = 2)
z(6)
# [1] 36
z@pow <- 3
z(6)
# [1] 216
```

I don't know whether `sys.function` exists when this question was firstly discussed, though.